# Do I need to include SASL in my Elixir application?

Tags: logging, elixir

I do not have SASL listed as a dependency or `extra_application` in my Elixir app. Do I need to include it somewhere so it's used in my distillery release?

Answer (score 0):

**No, distillery includes several applications by default in every release it generates. Including SASL.** Here is a snippet from the struct that contains the base release configuration:

```
        ...
        applications: [
          # required for elixir apps
          :elixir,
          # included so the elixir shell works
          :iex,
          # required for upgrades
          :sasl,
          ...
```

https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/blob/ad23d54b1f2f7f69acbba0e171f814f33f3a8bc1/lib/mix/lib/releases/models/release.ex